# What Am I puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**The answer to this puzzle is 9 letters long.**

---

**You will -> "_ _ _ _ _"** -> ?

**Before noon For each -> "_ _ _ _ _"** -> ?

**More (In some latin language) -> "_ _ _"** -> ?

**"Near" Gravity -> "_ _ _"** -> ?

**I/cosine -> "_ _ _ _ _ _"** -> ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's what I think the answer are

> **You will -> "YOULL"** (contraction)
>  **Before noon For each -> "AMPER"**  (AM+PER)
>  **More (In some latin language) -> "MÁS"** (Spanish)
>  **"Near" Gravity -> "NRG"**  (nr g)
>  **I/cosine -> "SECANT"**  (trig function which is reciprocal of *cosine*, thanks to M Oehm for a prompt on this one).

The point is that

> Each of these sounds like a physical quantity or unit - in order, **JOULE**, **AMPERE**, **MASS**, **ENERGY**, **SECOND** or, using symbols **J,A,m,E,s**.
>  Thus the answers spell out the name **JAMES** in an indirect way - through homophones.

What am I?

> Given that the question is phrased in this way, my guess is that the *What* refers to **WATT** (anothe physical unit).
>  Thus, the full answer is [**JAMES WATT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Watt)

Comment: (I guess the "trick" in the last one is that "cos" is spelled out and therefore the answer ‒ after re-interpreting ‒ should be, too)

Comment: @MOehm Ah yes, you are probably right actually. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it is, great job!